# Check if Cheetah Template Dict has key

Tags: python, templates, cheetah

I am trying to come up with a base template for an application and one of the goals would be to remove any unnecessary js/css from pages so I want to do something in the cheetah template like

```
#if $dict.has_key('datepicker'):
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="$datepicker" type="text/css" />
#end if
```

I think this would also help with errors like namemap does not have key 'datepicker'

my current error I am getting using WSGIHandler is

```
TypeError: descriptor 'has_key' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'str'
```

I feel like this has to do with me casting the return of the handler as a str but shouldnt the template be parsed before it gets to the str

```
t = Template(file=WORKSPACE_PATH+"/tmpl/posts.html", searchList=[tmpldict])
self.response_body = str(t).encode('utf8')
return str(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is this:

```
dict.has_key('datepicker')
```

"dict" is a class, so it expects the first argument of "dict.has_key" to be an instance of "dict".

You're passing a string instead of the dict object.

Basically, "d.has_key(k)" is equivalent to "dict.has_key(d, k)", and you have the latter.

Comment: I am just confused of how to reference the dict inside the template

Comment: After consulting the documentation, I'd say try #try...#except KeyError

Comment: but then if the key doesnt exist I will get a KeyError rather than what I want to do is just not include that key in the parsing

Comment: That's the point of the #try...#except KeyError: #pass, to trap and ignore the exception raised by the template line.